# How to create Footer which can be used for all the xamarin Form pages?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, footer

I am creating an app in which i want the footer which will be common for all xaml pages.I tried solution given on this link [xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59855/grid-xamarin-forms#latest)

but it is showing error for partial class bcoz I'm using **xamarin xaml form** page while inheriting the class **PageToInherit**.If I just use page (only .cs file) then there is no error.

```
public partial class TodoList : PageToInherit
{
    public TodoList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = "TodoList page";
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "BUTTON 1";

        MainStackLayout.Children.Add(button);

        Content = MainStackLayout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can take a look to [TemplatedPage](https://blog.xamarin.com/app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-control-templates/)

Create a ControlTemplate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Mobile.App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="Header Content" FontSize="24" />         
          <ContentPresenter />
        </StackLayout>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Apply the ControlTemplate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               x:Class="Mobile.MainPage"
               ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainPageTemplate}">

  <Label Text="Main Page Content" FontSize="18" />

</ContentPage>
```

Use TemplateBinding

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.HeadingText}" FontSize="24" />         
    <ContentPresenter />
  </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here the [Blog](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-page-templates/)

Comment: suppose in control template I have four images and on image click want navigate to another page , Where should I write code which will handle the Click event in App.cs or in Content page?

Comment: I don't know... I think in the same way you bind to HeadingText I think you can bind to a Command.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for this.

Use [ContentView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/) for creating reusable xaml views.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xxx.FooterView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="42" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}">
                <Label HeightRequest="42" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

and use it in your page like any control

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xxx.Page1" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx;assembly=xxx" >
    <local:FooterView VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="45"/>
//other views and layouts
</ContentPage>
```

Hope it helps.